# Power Automate Trigger "When a file is created or modified (properties only)" returns multiple items

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, power-automate, flow

Why SharePoint trigger `When a file is created or modified (properties only)` in Power Automate can sometimes return multiple items? From logical point of view, I would expect separate run per each action.

I was going to set the Trigger condition, but I can't now.

Microsoft official documentation kinda lack details why is that. ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#when-a-file-is-created-or-modified-(properties-only)))

> "**Returns:** The outputs of this operation are dynamic."

--

**Edit:**
I found a solution how to prevent it in [Power Automate White Paper](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/read-our-new-whitepaper-on-how-to-build-enterprise-ready-flows/) ([page 47 in PDF](https://clouddamcdnprodep.azureedge.net/gdc/gdc5fzAoK/original)) with `Split-On` option in trigger settings.

But I still don't understand how it can batch those actions?

[image: Trigger Advanced Settings]

> Split On: If your trigger returns an array for flow to process, a For
> each loop might sometimes  take too long to process all array items.
> Instead, you can use the Split On property in your trigger  to debatch
> the array. Debatching splits up the array items and starts a new logic
> app instance  that runs for each of those array items.

Comment: Ideally it should only return the single file properties when a file is created or modified. Can you show us how you are using flow and what `triggerOutputs` you got in flow?

Comment: Can you make sure that **Concurrency Control**  settings is disabled?

Comment: Concurrency control is disabled.